# Change date format in express using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I stored date in database but whenever i am fetching then its format change

```
getting date -      2018-07-31T06:48:01.649Z
stored date in db - 2018-07-31 12:18:01.649
```

here is my code

```
var timee = result.created;
```

Comment: in what format are you expecting the time to be?

Comment: @abdul : i want format which stored in database  2018-07-31 12:18:01.649

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/
You can still format your date on the frontend instead

Comment: try `var timee = new Date(result.created)`

Answer (score 1):

By default, dates are stored in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in MongoDB so you are seeing the difference in the time zone of stored and retrieved dates.

> new Date() returns the current date as a Date object. The mongo shell wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper. The ISODate is in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

You can read the MongoDB specification [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date).

There are several approaches that you can apply. Either convert the date to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) timezone before saving it or convert into locale time zone after loading the date.

```
new Date(ISODate().toString() + 'UTC')

ISODate("2018-08-01T11:39:39Z")
```

and to replace the T and Z with an empty space using the javascript.

```
dateString.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", " ");
```